# how not to trigger event child_added for initial children

Tags: firebase

I have rather big data-set, possibly millions of objects and I need to trigger the `child_added` event and get the last added child. However whenever I start the service it triggers the event once for each initial child in the data-set.

How Can I avoid this behavior?

edit:

The suggested solution does not solve the problem - it is just ignoring it in my opinion.  In my specific case I store the unique reference to other object as a `name` and it's `value` is other important data. The Priority on the record is set to the specific number in my case time stamp. I use this to retrieve the record to build a timeline so I need the option to save a new object with custom timestamp - not only current. Listener `.on()` on event `child_added` fits the need perfectly except fetching all the children upon the start. This in my opinion renders this feature absolutely pointless on any large collection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to discard initial data in a Firebase DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883736/how-to-discard-initial-data-in-a-firebase-db)

Comment: yes, the question is similar, but the solution is not there. As a matter of fact that is exactly what I dont want - fetch the entire snapshot...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3):

You could use `limit(1)`. Then the listener will fire once at the beginning, and then again each time a new child is added.

`fireRef.limit(1).on('child_added', function() { /*code*/ });`

Comment: yes, but please read the edit. this method only works if the new child is added at the bottom of the collection.

Comment: As far as I know, Firebase doesn't have a feature which allows what you're trying to do. The only way I know of to achieve what you're looking for is to use priority and a restriction such as `limit(1)`.