# child_added gets triggered after remove

Tags: javascript, firebase

I've created this handler to watch for new children being created. This little trick stops the child_added event from triggering my code on each page load. Instead it only gets triggered when something is actually added.

```
  // Listen for new rooms being created
  var first_room_added_after_load = true;
  this._roomRef.endAt().limit(1).on('child_added', function(snapshot){
      if (first_room_added_after_load) { // we want to skip the first room, because it will already exist
          first_room_added_after_load = false;
          return;
      }
      else {
          this._onCreateRoom(snapshot);
      }
  }, this);
```

That said, when I call remove() on a node in _roomRef then child_added is triggered for a node that already exists. Any hints as to why, and how to stop it?

I should also mention this only seems to happen if I remove something that was created after something else already in the list. If I remove the older items first, then child_added is not triggered.

Comment: If you are only interested in new items, why not remove or archive the old ones after processing? The list is only going to get longer over time, so data structure will be key here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to think the `endAt()` uses a timestamp for comparison, so that it only returns new children. But that's simply not how it works. From the [Firebase documentation for `endAt`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/endat.html):

> If no arguments are provided, the ending point will be the end of the data.

With your code:

```
this._roomRef.endAt().limit(1)
```

You're creating a query that is set to always return a single child. The condition is that the child was created after you created the query.

A query is like a sliding window over the child nodes in your Firebase ref: it will always contain (at most) one child, a child that was created after you created your query.

### Example

Say you have these children when you create the query:

```
child1
child2
child3 <!-- last child present when creating the endAt() query -->
```

By using `endAt` query will be "rooted" after `child3`. So it will not fire any events for `child1`, `child2` and `child3`.

Say you add a new child:

```
child1
child2
child3 <!-- last child present when creating the endAt() query -->
child4
```

The query will a `child_added` event for `child4`.

Now if we add another child:

```
child1
child2
child3 <!-- last child present when creating the endAt() query -->
child4
child5
```

The query will fire a `child_removed` for `child4` and `child_added` for `child5`. Note that `child4` was not actually removed from your Firebase, it just disappeared from the query results (since you asked to limit the number of results to just one).

When we now remove the latest child, we end up with:

```
child1
child2
child3 <!-- last child present when creating the endAt() query -->
child4
```

And the query will fire a `child_removed` for `child5` and `child_added` for `child4`. This again comes from the fact that your query is set to always contain (at most) one node that was added after `child3`.

### How to get what you want

It seems like you only want to get `child_added` once for newly added children. In that case I would not use a `limit` on the query, but instead I would set the timestamp that the room was created as its priority:

```
this._roomRef.push({
    /* whatever properties you need for a room */, 
    '.priority': Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP 
})
```

Then you can simply start the query at that priority.

```
this._roomRef.startAt(Date.now()).on('child_added', ...
```

Comment: Great answer. Another choice would be to use the [discard initial data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883736/how-to-discard-initial-data-in-a-firebase-db) approach. Less efficient but functional without priorities.

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm. I still don't understand why removing a node triggers child_added(), but it's working so it's hard to ask for more than that!

Comment: When you create a query with a `limit` in Firebase if starts acting more like a view. I tried explaining that in my example above, but can imagine it's tricky to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I found a tricky solution for this   .
Let's suppose you  are getting messages with value like
msg-txt  ,  timestamp ,  userid
When you get the first messages using child_added you need to store the latest message timestamp into a global variable then for every new chils_added just compare the two timestamps .

If the message timestamp > the global timestamp
Then return the message and save its timestamp to global timestamp.

Hope this will help

Comment: Please provide some code to supplement your explanation