# Starting a firebase query trigger at a possibly changing start value to efficiently get data after that point in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observer-pattern

**Edit 2**

This is my current setup. I am removing the observer when the side navigation view hides and restart it when it appears. This would be unnecessary if user defaults would return a fresh value in `queryStarting(atValue: defaults.double(forKey: lastReadMessageTimestampKey) + 0.000001)` like `timeIntervalSince1970` does in a similar query elsewhere: `queryStarting(atValue: NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)`.

```
class SideNavigationController: UIViewController {
    
    ...

    var unreadMessageCountUpdateQueryHandle: DatabaseHandle?

    ...
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        logger.info("SideNavigationControllers view will appear")

        updateUnreadMessagesCount()

        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        
        ...
    }


    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        logger.info("SideNavigationControllers view will disapear")
        
        stopUpdatingUnreadMessagesCount()
        
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        
        ...
    }

    func updateUnreadMessagesCount() {
        logger.info("Updating count of unread messages")

        let messageTimestampKey = DiscussionMessage.CodingKeys.messageTimestamp.stringValue
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
      
        unreadMessageCountUpdateQueryHandle = messagesReference.queryOrdered(byChild: messageTimestampKey).queryStarting(atValue: defaults.double(forKey: lastReadMessageTimestampKey) + 0.000001).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            if let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                print("Number of unread messages: \(value.count) Last Read TS \(UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: lastReadMessageTimestampKey))")
                self.menuItems[1].itemName = "Discussions (\(value.count))"
                self.sideNavTableView.reloadData()
            } else {
                self.menuItems[1].itemName = "Discussions"
                self.sideNavTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func stopUpdatingUnreadMessagesCount() {
        guard let handle = unreadMessageCountUpdateQueryHandle else { return }
        messagesReference.removeObserver(withHandle: handle)
    }
```

**Edit:**

Adding `.synchronize()` after saving the default value is not helping either.

I have also tweaked the query a little bit to start with an offset from the last read message's timestamp so that it won't be included when I count unread messages.

Now the query looks like this:

```
let discussionMessageTimestampKey = DiscussionMessage.CodingKeys.messageTimestamp.stringValue
messagesReference.queryOrdered(byChild: discussionMessageTimestampKey)
.queryStarting(atValue: UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: lastReadMessageTimestampKey) + 0.000001)
.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
    if let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
        print("Number of unread messages: \(value.count) Last Read TS \(UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: lastReadMessageTimestampKey))")
    }
}
```

With this query initially the unread messages count is `0` and then it becomes 1, 2, 3, etc. as new messages come in. This is even after I open the chat view and the last read message timestamp gets updated inside the query. I know that the last read message timestamp is updating as the console output looks like this:

```
Number of unread messages: 1 Last Read TS TS_OF_SECOND_LAST_MESSAGE
Number of unread messages: 2 Last Read TS TS_OF_SECOND_LAST_MESSAGE
Number of unread messages: 3 Last Read TS TS_OF_SECOND_LAST_MESSAGE
```

And my database structure looks like this for people who are curious:

[image: speech drill db structure 1]
[image: speech drill db structure 2]

Another way to do this might involve including 2 queries. Then the first query's execution could be stopped when the view is disappearing. But I don't know how to [stop a query execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66319294/how-to-stop-the-execution-of-a-firebase-query-observeeventtypewith) and could not find any documentation for it.

```
let messageTimestampKey = DiscussionMessage.CodingKeys.messageTimestamp.stringValue
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let query = messagesReference.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.exists() {
        let startTimestamp = defaults.double(forKey: lastReadMessageTimestampKey)
        let offset: Double = 0.00000001
        messagesReference.queryOrdered(byChild: messageTimestampKey).queryStarting(atValue: startTimestamp + offset).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            if let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                print("Number of unread messages: \(value.count) Last Read TS \(UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: lastReadMessageTimestampKey))")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

I am creating a chat app and I want to count the number of unread messages. The value of the last read timestamp is saved at a location in my realtime database and each message has a timestamp attached to it. The last read message's timestamp is also stored in user defaults. So I tried using that value with `queryStarting(atValue:)`. But it is not working as expected. Even after the default's value gets updated, the query still uses an older value, and unread message count keeps going up with `.value` event. With `.childAdded` event, I keep getting a constant (always incorrect) count even when new messages are added.

```
let discussionMessageTimestampKey = DiscussionMessage.CodingKeys.messageTimestamp.stringValue
messagesReference.queryOrdered(byChild: discussionMessageTimestampKey).queryStarting(atValue: UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: lastReadMessageTimestampKey)).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
    if let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
        print("Number of unread messages: \(value.count) Last Read TS \(UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: lastReadMessageTimestampKey))")
    }
}
```

I am using a [similar query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736714/in-firebase-ios-sdk-childadded-is-triggered-every-time-a-child-is-deleted-how/65957623#65957623) for firing `.childAdded` event only for newly added messages and not deleted messages. Here I have a strong feeling that `NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970` keeps returning a fresh value whenever a child is added or deleted. As even if 4 messages are added after the query was created and 1 of them was deleted, this event is not triggered. As it is designed to be triggered as explained by Frank [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736714/in-firebase-ios-sdk-childadded-is-triggered-every-time-a-child-is-deleted-how/65957623#65957623).

```
let discussionMessageTimestampKey = DiscussionMessage.CodingKeys.messageTimestamp.stringValue
messagesReference.queryOrdered(byChild: discussionMessageTimestampKey).queryStarting(atValue: NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970).observe(.childAdded) { 
    (snapshot) in
    ...
}
```

This brings me to my question. Since the user defaults query is not working, and the last read message timestamp is also stored in firebase. Can we maybe use that value as `queryStarting(atValue:)` instead (as I am hoping it will return a fresh value like `NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970` does). The problem here is that both the last read message timestamp and the number of messages can change. Hence if I create an observer on one, then it will lead to unnecessary data loading at another end. Could someone explain to me why the query works as expected with `NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970` but not with `UserDefaults`? And how I can fix this issue of counting number of unread messages optimally.

(One method I thought of involved adding a KVO on user defaults. But I saw [that process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43963220/how-to-use-kvo-for-userdefaults-in-swift) also has complications so I did not go down that route.)

Comment: Can you share more code and how your database structure look like?

Comment: I will add-in sometime

Comment: added db strucuture

Answer (score 0):

There are few solution I can think of for this issue. I am not sure how is your data structure on Firebase. I assume you will have a list of `messages` and `user` node.

If your goal is to count unread message.

You can try changing your approach. When you get new message from `.childAdded` you might want store it into respective `user` node and remove it when you trigger read action on specific message. It's more efficient this way, especially when you have larger message later on. Or instead of adding a new node just update the value of `totalUnreadMessage` in your `user` node

Your node should look similar like this

```
root
|
- users
  |
  - 0
    |
    - totalUnreadMessage : 10  << update this when there is new message for this user
```

Additionally regarding your query, why it doesn't work when you use UserDefaults, most likely because the data type mismatch. eg: You are storing `Date` which is an object and trying to retrieve `double` value.

If you plan to use the last read message timestamp, I feel it won't be as efficient as adjusting how you store or calculate total unread message as above.

Comment: I don't think mismatch is an issue. The query works as expected on the first run. Also my question is, if it works for `NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970` then it should work for something else too. Which leads me  to believe that `NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970` keep returning new value where as `UserDefaults` does not.

Comment: @ParthTamane I see, I misunderstood.

Yes you are right `NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970` will always return a new value. `UserDefault` wont' because it store the value, so it will return the exact same value as what you store.

Comment: Yes, but I am updating that value in a different place.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with offline persistence enabled

Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true

try to disable it by changing this line to

Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = false

Comment: By similar issues what exactly are you referring to?  Can you add an example to your answer?

Comment: I mean changes weren't reflecting on next queries.
Just disable offline persistence if it is on.

Comment: Do you mean changes to user defaults? And so should I explicitly add "Database.database().isPersistanceEnabled = false" before I start this query?

Comment: I mean your changes to firebase when reread, will not receive latest updates if you use offline persistence. which can create a situation of inconsistency that probably cause your issue

Comment: Can you try and please share results?

Comment: But I am using the starting at with timeIntergalSince1970 elsewhere in my app and that query runs properly. But this one does not.

Comment: Then probably UserDefaults is the issue

Comment: Any idea why it's not returning a fresh value?

Comment: do you sync values after updating? use synchronize()

Comment: No I don't cause I read it's not necessary to call it. I think you are referring to [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647931/nsuserdefaults-synchronize-method/9647965#9647965), both of which state it's not needed...

Comment: just try it, will not hurt.

Comment: Yup I'll check it later!

Comment: `.synchronize()` did not help. :(