# Watching for new adds in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

From the Firebase [documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html):

> The child_added event is typically used when retrieving a list of
>   items from the database. Unlike value which returns the entire
>   contents of the location, child_added is triggered once for each
>   existing child and then again every time a new child is added to the
>   specified path. The event callback is passed a snapshot containing the
>   new child's data. For ordering purposes, it is also passed a second
>   argument containing the key of the previous child.

I'm currently using the following code to watch for changes:

```
ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
}, function(errorObject) {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject);
});
```

However, the first time I call `ref.on("child_added", ...)` I see all current children at this path, as specified by the docs

> child_added is triggered once for each
>   existing child and then again every time a new child is added to the
>   specified path

Is there a way to just listen for new adds?

Comment: How are you loading in the initial data set for your app?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978078/how-to-separate-initial-data-load-from-incremental-children-with-firebase

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you very much.