# how to pass dictionary with key to table view

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

```
    import UIKit
import Firebase

class PendingVC: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

let ref = firebasehelper.firebaseURL()
var data = [[:]]




//MARK: vars
        var address:AnyObject!
        var postTitle:AnyObject!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTableView.dataSource = self
        myTableView.delegate = self
```

//The example below work great I get the layout the way it should look, but i want to generate the dictionary from  the firebase function below.

```
/*
     self.data = [
     [
     "firstname": "sallie",
     "lastname": "ammy"
     ],
     [
     "firstname": "jamie",
     "lastname": "brown"
     ]
     ]

     */
```

It should look something like this and i want to past the data to the table. Im not sure if i should be looping. the way it is below bring the following error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" the variables are not nil when i print them i get data back.

```
ref.childByAppendingPath("backend/posts").queryOrderedByChild("requestFrom").queryEqualToValue(ref.authData.uid).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {snapshot in
                var firstname = snapshot.value["firstname"] as! String
                var lastname = snapshot.value["lastname"] as! String


         self.data = [
            [
                "firstname": firstname,
                "lastname": lastname
            ]
        ]



       print(self.data)
    })







}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! statusPrototypeCell


    let object = data[indexPath.row]



cell.firstname.text = object["firstname"] as! String
  cell.lastname.text = object["lastname"] as! String


    return cell
}


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false

    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.4, green:0.76, blue:0.93, alpha:1.0)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
    self.title = "Signup"

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
}
}
```

Comment: `[:]` is a dictionary not an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can use a dictionary as a dataSource, it's unordered which means the items in your tableView will also be unordered. Using an array is a better solution. In fact, an array of dictionaries make a nice ordered data source.

Also, to clarify, you don't pass a dictionary or data to a tableView per your question. The tableView gathers it's data from a datasource via it's delegate methods

Assume the following Firebase data structure

```
"users" : {
    "uid_0" : {
      "first_name" : "Bill",
      "last_name" : "Nye"
    },
    "uid_1" : {
      "first_name" : "Leroy",
      "last_name" : "Jenkins"
    },
    "uid_2" : {
      "first_name" : "Peter",
      "last_name" : "Sellers"
    }
  }
```

and to populate an array of dictionaries:

```
var usersArray: [Dictionary<String, String>] = []

let usersRef = self.myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("users")

usersRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in

  var userDict = [String:String]()
  userDict["key"] = snapshot.key
  userDict["firstName"] = snapshot.value["first_name"] as? String
  userDict["lastName"] = snapshot.value["last_name"] as? String         
  self.usersArray.append(userDict)
})
```

to access the data, use the keys you created above.

For example: to print the users in the array from a button

```
for userDict in self.usersArray {
    let key = userDict["key"]
    let fName = userDict["firstName"]
    let lName = userDict["lastName"]

    print("\(key!)  \(fName!)  \(lName!)")
}
```

Once you have an understanding of that, you can then use the usersArray to populate the tableView.

```
let userDict = usersArray[indexPath.row]
cell.firstname.text = userDict["firstName"] as! String
cell.lastname.text = userDict["lastName"] as! String
```

The tricky bit is loading the array with all of the data needed, *then* reload the tableView to display it. If you have a small set of data, .Value will work for that. A larger set of data requires another technique, see [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978078/how-to-separate-initial-data-load-from-incremental-children-with-firebase)

Comment: one thing i realize is that .ChildAdded kept returning the items nil. once i did change that to .Value I was able to get the data from Firebase. in the cellForRowAtIndexPath function I receive "fatal error: Index out of range" at the "let userDict = usersArray[indexPath.row]"

Comment: @peter That's because when you use .Value, it returns everything in that node; all child nodes, their children etc etc. With .Value you will need to iterate over the child nodes using *for child in snapshot.children*, and then build your dictionary from each *child* within that loop. After the loop concludes, call *tableView.reloadData*

Comment: everything work great until i try to place UserDict outside of  the firebase closure into the tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath function. I tried to declare the variable outside of the firebase Function before I used it but no luck. I also trying to use the firebase function inside a function but once again it will be inside a closure so it will not work. Ive been pulling my hair out trying to figure this out but no luck.

Comment: @peter Why would you place UserDict outside of the firebase closure? Your **ARRAY** is what holds the data for the tableView. That array is a series of dictionaries. The array is defined outside the closure by this line var usersArray: [Dictionary<String, String>] = [] and is populated with dictionaries inside the closure. The array will 'hang around' and can be accessed anywhere else within the class (or function depending on where you put it)

Answer (score 0):

You are using Dictionary so it doesn't returning count value so better to use array like [] instead of [:]

One more thing You have forgot the following statement to include in ViewDidLoad method
myTableView.delegate = self

Comment: @ramaKrisma i was able to place the dictionary to the table, the issue Im having now is generating the data I get a nil answer Im not sure why  please take a look at the question edit.