# Is it possible to detect when a Firebase snapshot has been executed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I am executing the following Firebase query:

```
var getAdmin = function() {
    var rootRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URI),
        adminList = [],
        deferred = $q.defer();

    rootRef.child('user').orderByChild('role').startAt(21).once('child_added',  function (administrator) {
        // Add each Administrator to Admin List
        adminList.push(administrator);
    });

    // deferred.resolve(?)

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

I want to resolve the promise with the list of Administrators. How do I detect when the Firebase snapshot has been fully executed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to discard initial data in a Firebase DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883736/how-to-discard-initial-data-in-a-firebase-db)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase is a realtime platform, so a list is never 'fully executed'.

If you just want that part of the list at that instant in time, you should use `.once('value', callback)`.

```
rootRef.child('user').orderByChild('role').startAt(21).once('value', function(list) {

    // Add each Administrator to Admin List
    list.forEach(function(adminSnap) {
        adminList.push(adminSnap.val());
    });

    deferred.resolve(adminList)
});

return deferred.promise;
```

Comment: Thanks Anid. I was looking at this in the wrong way.