# Firebase, only get new children

Tags: javascript, firebase

```
var firebase = new Firebase("....");
firebaseRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
     ...
}
```

This will receive all elements, is there a way to not receive all children when creating a new Firebase reference? Only get new?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788902/firebase-child-added-only-get-child-added

Comment: wow... can't beleive i missed that, sorry guys! thanks Bernhard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering question: 
Source: [Firebase child_added only get child added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788902/firebase-child-added-only-get-child-added)
Pointed out by: [@Bernherd Hoffman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/39722/bernhard-hofmann%20@Bernhard%20Hoffman)

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase("...");

firebaseRef.endAt().limit(1).on('child_added', function(snapshot){
//Do your stuff
});
```

Note: you will get 1 previous record, you you can filter that out.

Comment: what a clever API.. It's so sad this hasn't improved in 2 years :/

Comment: @EralpB very sad indeed :-/