# Firebase observe with type .childAdded retrieves all my information every time. Please assist

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

According to Firebase docs:

> ChildAdded is triggered once for each existing child and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path

So, I have an app, that has a little banner at the top that pops up every time a user gets a new message. As you could have guessed, these messages are stored in a child in the user object in Firebase. So, here's the problem, when I load the app, it pops up for EVERY message the user has. Is it possible to have this observe event ONLY be called when a new child is added? I don't want it to be triggered for every single existing child, only when a new one is added. I would hate to have to store message references in core data, and do a check for every child to see if it already exists in core data :/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A few ways to do this:

- Use [`ref.queryLimitedToLast(1)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_database_reference.html#a88c088c33be888a2e1ffe1714525307a) when you start. See [Firebase, only get new children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874141/firebase-only-get-new-children).
- keep track of the most recent key you've got in your local storage and then query with [`queryOrderByKey()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_database_reference.html#a2c537bb6dbc613244d334730e7deb567)`.queryStartingAtValue(latestKey)`
- Add a timestamp to the items and then [`queryOrderByChild("timestamp")`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_database_reference.html#a784fc0edfe5f69db8fd44702507e1cc7)`.queryStartingAt(now)` for items with timestamp >= now. See [how to discard initial data in a Firebase DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883736/how-to-discard-initial-data-in-a-firebase-db/27693310#27693310)

Comment: Thanks Frank you're a legend, always coming in clutch