# Notification on New Child added to Fire-base Database , by using Service

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-service

But this code is showing Notification on Every App Launch and Multiple Times a day even if no Child is added to database 
Please help me resolve this issue , I've tried using `onDatabaseChange` Method but same thing is happening

```
if (mChildEventListener == null) {
    mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mnotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_chat)
                    .setContentTitle("You may have New Messages !!")
                    .setContentText("Check Chat Room > Received > New Message")
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));



                notificationManager.notify(0, mnotificationBuilder.build());

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you attach a `ChildEventListener` to a location, its `onChildAdded` is immediately called for all existing child nodes at the location. So it sounds like the code is working as expected.

It also sounds like you're trying to only notify the user of **new** child nodes, probably meaning child nodes that they haven't seen yet.

A simple way to do this is to keep track of that most recent child node you've shown to a user. For example by storing the key of that node in the [shared preferences of the app](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage#pref). Then when you load the app, you read the key from the shared preferences and start retrieving nodes from there on.

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages").orderByKey();
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String last_seen_message_key = prefs.getString("last_seen_message_key", null);
if (last_seen_message_key != null) {
  query = query.startAt(last_seen_message_key)
}
query.addChildEventListener(...
```

For more on this, also see:

- [Firebase: Get New Child Added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549890/firebase-get-new-child-added)
- [How to retrieve only new data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270995/how-to-retrieve-only-new-data)
- [Firebase child_added only get child added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788902/firebase-child-added-only-get-child-added)
- [Firebase, only get new children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874141/firebase-only-get-new-children)
- [Get only new "child added" after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493719/get-only-new-child-added-after-page-load)