# Retrieve only childAdded from firebase to my listener in firebase

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I currently have this python script running

```
# Setup Firebase Listner

# Retrieve the data from Firebase and do the analysis

# Append the data to Firebase

from firebase_streaming import Firebase

# Firebase object
fb = Firebase('https:***************.firebaseio.com/')


# Callback function to Analyze the data for a Faulty Motor
def performAnalysis_FaultyMotor(x):
    print(x)

def performAnalysis_motor(x):
    print(x)

# Declaring Custom callback definitions for the faulty and motor data
custom_callback_faultyMotor = fb.child("accelerometerData/faultyMotorData").listener(performAnalysis_FaultyMotor)
custom_callback_motor = fb.child("accelerometerData/motorData").listener(performAnalysis_motor)


# Start and stop the stream using the following
custom_callback_faultyMotor.start()
custom_callback_motor.start()
```

which is returning me the entire data under the respective node that I have my listener attached to.

**But I require specifically only the newly added child under that node.**

Any idea how could I achieve that???

Answer (score 1):

Firebase synchronizes database state, it is not a message passing mechanism.

This means that if you attach a listener on a node, you get all data under that node. If you only want new data, you'll have to define what "new" means.

For example: if new means data added after you attach a listener, then you may want to add a timestamp in your child nodes and filter on that.

Alternatively, you can request only the most recent child_added event. I'm not sure how to do that with the Python library you're using, but in JavaScript it would be `firebase.database().ref('accelerometerData/faultyMotorData').orderByKey().limitToLast(1).on('child_added'...`.

Also see:

- [How to retrieve only new data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270995/how-to-retrieve-only-new-data)
- [How to only get new data without existing data from a Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885059/how-to-only-get-new-data-without-existing-data-from-a-firebase)
- [How to get only the new items added to firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648907/how-to-get-only-the-new-items-added-to-firebase)
- [Firebase child_added only get child added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788902/firebase-child-added-only-get-child-added)